# Xcode Adaptive Layout - Specific image sizes

Tags: xcode, autolayout, adaptive-layout

I'm building a UI for the iPhone in portrait mode only.  The UI contains several images.  The images are different sizes based on the device.  For example, on an iPhone 5 a button is 250x250, but on an iphone 6 it's 295x295.  The problem is that the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 both use the same 2x rendered image from assets.

Other then detecting the size of the display in code and setting the UIImageView source, is it possible to set the image in a Adaptive layout class size?

Adaptive layout does not seem to allow that fine of a distinction.